# Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have problem to create @Bean with paramaters this runs fine but in the intelliJ it gives this error Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found.

what I am tying to do? I am trying to create bean that has protoType scope and I get this error in the IntelliJ "Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found." on the paramters can any one help me to solve this one

[image]

this is the class of the ProtoTypeTest

[image]

Comment: Error raised by intellij is a valid one, prototype test expects two autowired strings, how are you injecting those properties here?

Comment: I will edit the post by adding the ProtoTypTest class

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I have edited the post by adding the class of ProtoTypeTest

Comment: It is still unclear how you intend to autowire the Strings. Maybe asking it a bit differently: what are you expecting Spring to set the values of `firstName` and `lastName` to?

Comment: okay I wanted to apply the command pattern in spring boot for this purpose I was looking for how I can do it. for example i would like each time to pass new object of ProtoTypeTest but I should pass two parameters in runtime and excute method to do one job using these paramters, here the example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton in the last point 8. Create a Bean at Runtime Using java.util.Function

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj if u can tell me how I can apply it or just give an example

Answer (score 4):

There is actually nothing wrong with what you're doing, contrary to what the other comments say. It is even possible to auto-inject `ObjectProvider<PrototypeTest> prototypeTestProvider` into some other class and call it with `prototypeTestProvider.getObject("John", "Wick")` and have it succeed. I like your BiFunction approach better because it is compile-time checked, whereas "getObject"'s parameters are not.

So, why is Intellij complaining? because the Spring plugin to Intellij is not aware of this aspect of Spring. I suggest you find a way to ignore the error. I'd either not rely on the plugin, check for an update of it, or else check if updating Intellij fixes the issue (but I would guess not).